# How to build a standard KPI tile in SAP FIORI

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement to make a tile on the Fiori launchpad that sends a parameter to be consumed by an oData. Dynamic tiles do not work because I can't send dynamic values throughout launchpad designer.

This is what I want to make:

[image]

The logged user ID needs to be passed to the oData and the only solution is to make a standard KPI tile but I can't find any documentation or a guide.
I was able to find a few documents, but they don't have enough info:

- [Implementing a Custom Tile Type](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc1c7615ee2f4a699a9272453379006c/7.5.9/en-US/3ff37eb5e28a4da5b5b152b036776c98.html)
- [CHIP Definition XML](https://help.sap.com/viewer/fd097bb01d75492b9b8bb0ae0e38ad75/7.5.9/en-US/91ebf3ff6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)
- https://blogs.sap.com/2016/08/23/create-and-use-custom-tile-type/

Comment: Can you please be more specific - what exactly does not work?

Comment: i want to create a standard KPI tile that send and recieve data from odata, dynamic tiles only recieve data :/ but i need to send a parameter to show some specific info in the tile